# Can't grab some content using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I've written some code in `python` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` to get some `addresses` within `br` tag. If it is about parsing the required text using `BeautifulSoup` alone, I could have done this using `.next_sibling` which I've shown below. My intention is to scrape the content within `br` in combination with `BeautifulSoup` and `re`.

This is my try so far:

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

content = """
<div class="store"">
<b>address</b><br>BLOCK ANG MO KIO AVE<br>
<b>address_one</b><br>BLOCK 407 ANG MO KIO AVE 10 #01-741<br>
<b>address_two</b><br>NO. 53 ANG MO KIO AVE 3 AMK HUB#B1-82<br>
</div>
"""
# soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
# for addr in soup.find_all("b"):
#     print(addr.next_sibling.next_sibling)

soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
for addr in soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"<br>(.*?)</br>")):
    print(addr)  #It prints nothing, no error either
```

FYI, the commented out portion is just working flawlessly if uncommented. As I'm trying to figure out what would be the usage of `re` in such cases, I would be very happy if someone provided me with a helping hand.

Comment: As you can see, `text` only means the inner text of a tag, and it does not "see" `br` tag, it is not correct way to use `text`. Besides, it would just fetch the whole node that contains some text in its inner text, it would not extract any substrings from them. This will extract those nodes since they will match fully: `soup.find_all(text=re.compile(r"^[A-Z0-9#.-]+(?:\s+[-.#A-Z0-9]+)*$"))`

Comment: There are no closing `</br>` tags. `br` is just a line break - it should not have closing tags

Comment: Consider providing it as an answer. Your suggested approach worked wonderfully @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: @Wiktor Stribiżew, I could not understand this `*` used just before `$`. As there is already a `+` within non capturing group.

Comment: The quantifier affects the whole sequence of patterns inside a group. Else, it would match `ABC DEF` only strings. With `*`, it matches `ABC`, `ABC DEF`, `A-C B.F H#D` strings.

Comment: I don't see why I should post an answer since you already accepted another one, that actually proves you only wanted to extract any text between two tags/strings. Right?

Comment: What sir Andersson has provided is a workaround but the way you have suggested is what my expected solution was. The checkmark is not meant to be hardcoded ever @Wiktor Stribiżew.

Comment: Well, I am not sure my approach is actually going to help much since it is based on creating very specific pattern that should match the whole string. Are you sure I should post an answer? Is the question about matching strings that should fully match some pattern or just extracting text from between two tags (as is actually implied by your own attempt)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use regex you can try below:

```
for addr in re.findall(r"<br>(.*?)<br>", content):
    print(addr)
```

The output is

```
BLOCK ANG MO KIO AVE
BLOCK 407 ANG MO KIO AVE 10 #01-741
NO. 53 ANG MO KIO AVE 3 AMK HUB#B1-82
```

Comment: You must have meant to use  a lazy version, `r"<br>(.*?)<br>"`.